# What is the Eclipse attack and how was it fixed in Ethereum?

Tags: attacks

In this paper the researchers describe the Eclipse attack https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/263.pdf. Can someone explain it briefly, what steps an attacker needs to take to perform the attack and how it will affect the system.

What changes in the code fixed this vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

It seems Geth v1.8.1 can prevent that kind of attack, according to https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/researchers-explore-eclipse-attacks-ethereum-blockchain/

> (The researchers disclosed their attacks to Ethereum on January 9, 2018, and Ethereum developers have already issued a patch — Geth v1.8.1 — to fix the network.)
>
> In speaking with Bitcoin Magazine, Goldberg explained the research, how it compares to Bitcoin eclipse attacks and why she thinks the work is important.